# Javascript issue with looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I've got a bit of a problem with some javascript I'm trying to make work the JS functions are below

```
var changing_thumbs = new Array();
function changeThumb(index, i, thumb_count, path) {
    if (changing_thumbs[index]) {
        if (path.indexOf('imageCount=') !== -1) {
            lastIndexOfEquals = path.lastIndexOf('=');
            path = path.substring(0, lastIndexOfEquals + 1);
            $j('#' + index).attr('src', path + i);
        }
        else {
            $j('#' + index).attr('src', path + '&imageCount=' + i);
        }
            i = i % thumb_count + 1;
        changing_thumbs[index] = setTimeout("changeThumb('" + index + "', '" + i + "', '" + thumb_count + "', '" + path + "')", 600);
    }
}
function startVideoPreview(index, thumb_count, path) {
   changing_thumbs[index] = true;
   changeThumb(index, 1, thumb_count, path);
}
function endVideoPreview(index, path) {
   clearTimeout(changing_thumbs[index]);
   document.getElementById(index).src = path;
}
```

The html calling is below

```
<img id="3a80b9aa-8b2f-4fb9-b3b0-02b2f55bf3be" src="/Image/GetClipImg?photoID=3a80b9aa-8b2f-4fb9-b3b0-02b2f55bf3be&userID=2" alt="Test Clip Description" onmouseout="endVideoPreview('3a80b9aa-8b2f-4fb9-b3b0-02b2f55bf3be', '/Image/GetClipImg?photoID=3a80b9aa-8b2f-4fb9-b3b0-02b2f55bf3be&userID=2')" onmouseover="startVideoPreview('3a80b9aa-8b2f-4fb9-b3b0-02b2f55bf3be', 7, '/Image/GetClipImg?photoID=3a80b9aa-8b2f-4fb9-b3b0-02b2f55bf3be&userID=2')">
```

Everything seems to work fine but these two lines

```
i = i % thumb_count + 1;
changing_thumbs[index] = setTimeout("changeThumb('" + index + "', '" + i + "', '" + thumb_count + "', '" + path + "')", 600);
```

Never get hit after executing the previous IF statement they just get stepped over. I'm sure this is going to be something basic but I'm newish to JS and I can't seem to see what the problem is. Any hints or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You should consider debugging your code with FireBug or the IE Developer Tools.  Step through the code and see how the value of 'i' is mutated over the course of the script execution.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Glenn I have been trying to debug with Firebug, I've stepped through the code it hits this line:

    `$j('#' + index).attr('src', path + '&imageCount=' + i);`

And then jumps out of the function, it never hits the line to increment i and recall the function.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` need a callback.

And don't use string as the first parameter, use a function.

Try this:

```
changing_thumbs[index] = setTimeout(function() {
  changeThumb(index, i, thumb_count, path);
}, 600);
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz but the code doesn't manage to hit that part of the code at the moment it get to `$j('#' + index).attr('src', path + '&imageCount=' + i);` and then jumps out of the function.